# Link to a review in the review queue from the flag status page

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

So, say you flag an post as VLQ and it heads off to the review queue.

A little while later, you head over to your flags to check the status and see that it is `disputed`. So, you go back to the answer and see that it has a comment from a reviewer that is typical for link-only answers (which it was).

You'd like to see what the reviews were on the flag (how "disputed" it was). Then what?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but, as far as I know, you can't search the review queues or view their global history, so there's no way to find the review. I'm also aware that editing the answer resets the flag, but that was not the case for this post.

[It would be quite useful to be able to click on `disputed` (or `helpful` or `declined`) and have it direct to the review where the decision was made.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265648/link-to-a-review-in-the-review-queue-from-the-flag-status-page#comment62685_265648)

Currently, the only way to do this is to hope that you can find it in the review history of the recent reviewers in the queue (or in the global review history if you have 10k+ mod tools). Thanks to [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene), you can now [pull up the review history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265661/3366929) of any question if you have its ID.

However, both of these solutions are unnecessarily clunky and there should be an easier (and more reliable: neither guarantee you'll find anything) way to find reviews of your flagged posts in the way that you can find suggested edits reviews from a post's edit history.

[image: Link to review from flag result page]

## To be clear, this *is* a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and not a flag complaint.

Comment: It's possible (you can look through the whole history, page by page) but it's not practical if the item wasn't just recently reviewed.  (For SO "recently" usually means the past few minutes.  For non-SO sites it usually means hours/days.)

Comment: @Servy That's what I was referring to with "global history." Do you have a link to that? There's no way I'll find it now, but it'd be nice to have for future reference.

Comment: Moderators have tools for pulling this up immediately on any post, but not average users. Making this public has been requested before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192238/make-the-show-review-history-mod-tool-available-on-suggested-edits-for-everyon

Comment: @AstroCB 10K users have access to the full review history, but us mere mortals can only see our own history.  It's impossible to get this information at all.

Comment: @BradLarson That makes sense for mods to have, but it would be really helpful to see how reviews were handled so that you can base your later flags off of that. This was a typical "I think this will be useful to you" + a couple words of explanation + link answer and I'm curious to see how it was reviewed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, I see. So, what I'm hearing is that to even be able to have a chance of finding a review, I have to gain about 8500 rep, become an elected moderator, and/or get a job at SE.

Comment: If I believe it's particularly wrong and it was disputed relatively recently, I sometimes search the profiles of each user that has reviewed recently to see whether I can find the post. It works about 60% of the time for me.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I do that as well, but by the time I saw that this one was disputed, it was too late.

Comment: Linking to completed reviews from a flag state is reasonable.

Comment: @Shog9 Any chance of it happening?

Comment: I just started typing out a very similar feature request, saw there was already one, got excited, saw it's been inactive to a year... since ["disputed" seems to be more of a thing now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday) it would be *really nice* if people could see how their flags turned out and let them learn whether the disputed state is due to the flag being bad, or the review being bad.

Answer (score 6):

You can't find that easy at runtime but the review info for posts is exported to [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com). Reviews are anonymous in SEDE though.

[Find reviews for a post](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208490/find-the-reviews-for-a-post?postid=16738968) shows for a given post the reviewtasks and its results.

```
-- postid: id of the post "id found when you share an anwer or the link in the url"
select r.id
     , r.postid as [Post Link]
     , r.creationdate
     , r.deletiondate
     , rt.Name as [Type] 
     , rts.name as [State]
     , rtrt.name as [Result]
     , rtr.creationdate
     , re.name as [Reject reason]
     , rtr.comment
from reviewtasks r
left outer join reviewtasktypes rt on rt.id = r.ReviewTaskTypeId
left outer join ReviewTaskStates rts on rts.id = r.reviewtaskstateid
left outer join ReviewTaskResults rtr on rtr.reviewtaskid = r.id
left outer join ReviewTaskResultTypes rtrt on rtrt.id = rtr.ReviewTaskResultTypeId
left outer join ReviewRejectionReasons re on re.id = rtr.RejectionReasonid
where r.postid = ##postid##
```

The answer you referred to in your question is only 15 hours old so this query becomes only useful for that answer monday next weeek. Instead I used an answer with some reviewtaks to demo the functionality.

Comment: Nice: thanks for writing this. I still think it's silly that we can't get to the reviews directly, though, so I'm leaving the question open, but I'll check on it next week.

Answer (score 3):

While there still isn't a direct link to the review from the flag status page there now is another way to get to the actual review: As Shog9 has pointed it out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277336) (about a year ago)

> As of today, you can find links to completed review tasks via the
>   timeline for any post.

For anyone who doesn't know how to access the post timeline (since there is no direct link to this one either), you have to change the URL of the post that was reviewed to

```
http://{site}.stackexchange.com/posts/{id}/timeline
```

or if the post is on SO

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/timeline
```

By the way: [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340703/6214222) a feature-request to show a direct link to the timeline of any post which would make things even easier, but at least using the timeline we can now get to the actual review.

<sub>I thought I'd update the status of this question so that other people interested in this functionality (like me) won't have to search through multiple meta questions on different SE sites in order to find a solution - or maybe even think there isn't one because they didn't see any more answers to this question here.</sub>