# How to view the review status page in future..?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

After reviewing something, If I click the back button I can see the status of that review like:

> [image]

Is there a way I can easily get to this page in the future..?

For example, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13640273/2333214) with many upvotes as *not an answer*, and it was *disputed*.

(I know what *disputed* means, this isn't another *Y my flag s declined* post).

Now, I'd like to know how many of the community agreed with me and how many didn't, so that I can make better decisions in future.

---

I saw [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265648/2333214), and according to comments,

> 10K users have access to the full review history, but us mere mortals can only see our own history. It's impossible to get this information at all.

I know it is possible to view this somehow, since the back button leads me to the status page.

How do I go to the same status page in future..?

Answer (score 1):

> 10K users have access to the full review history, but us mere mortals can only see our own history. It's impossible to get this information at all.

This 10K privilege refers to https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history and the same page in each of the other queues.  10K users can see every review, whereas <10K users only see our own.

So unless you are willing to wade through that list and look manually, then there is no way for non-moderators to get to that specific page except by pressing the back button, like you found.  The SEDE query mentioned by rene in the [post you linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265661/250725) is the only alternative to getting the info you want.

Comment: reminder ~ the SEDE database is only updated once a week, each sunday.