# Lots of disputed flags since yesterday

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, triage

I've been going through the Triage queue for quite some time now. However, since yesterday, 11 of my flags have been marked "disputed", almost half of my total disputed flags. I do know that disputed flags don't necessarily mean anything bad, but the sudden flood is a bit disconcerting.

I noticed further that two of the questions I have flagged got placed on hold anyway for the same reason that I have flagged them. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485924/sql-server-insert-records and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486044/xml-data-not-found-404 were put on hold for the exact same reason that I have flagged them, but they were marked disputed anyway.

Should I be reevaluating my flagging because of this?

---

Edit: The situation is getting exasperating. Some examples from today:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7677255
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7677257

Either people are clicking "Should be improved" without knowing what it really means, or they know that the question has problems, but they can't be assed to complete the "Unsalvagable" popup.

Either way, something needs to be done. I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one getting discouraged with the higher-than-usual Triage disputes. Also, I'm pretty sure this is also throwing some garbage in the Help and Improvement queue.

Comment: I don't think anything in particular has changed since yesterday. Perhaps a different set of reviewers were looking over the posts that you have flagged recently.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I at least hope that mine is an isolated case. It's still uncomfortable knowing that I might not be doing something correctly lately.

Comment: Could be a couple of things here. 1. you could have robo-reviewers approving posts or choosing a different option from you, which would give you a disputed flag. 2. as there are no filters on the triage queue, people might be reviewing items that they have no subject knowledge of, and they approve rather than skip. I'd agree with both of your review decisions shown here, so don't reevaluate what you're doing.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Disputed vs. accepted/declined flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-accepted-declined-flags).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yup, I've read that one, which is why I know that disputed flags are not necessarily bad. The amount of them in a short span of time is just uncomfortable.

Comment: @Tanner I guess, but that is how it has been since the beginning. I would have gotten a lot more disputed flags if that's the sole reason. But thanks for the vote of confidence. Really appreciated.

Comment: I also see many more disputed flags this week than last week, and things flagged for closure being "disputed" but then still closed.

Comment: I've had the same experience, actually: I flagged [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29490356/4200092) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29510395/4200092) as "Too Broad" and both flags were disputed - now they're both on hold.

Comment: "disputed" (in SO mod terminology) means that someone disagreed with your flag. It doesn't mean that the flag was not accepted.

Comment: I noticed that rise in disputed flags too (and the rise in meta topics about that). I thought it was a coincidence caused by minor edits to the flagged questions, but maybe someone is out there reviewing flags and disputing everything? Hopefully someone who can take some action about it will notice as well.

Comment: If it helps provide more context, these were all disputed in Triage review. Here are some of the reviews: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7611446 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7611533 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7611530 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7611150 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7611455 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7596848 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7596628

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, I've got more disputed flags in the last 2 days than in the previous 14 months. It seems like if I select "unsalvageable" in triage, but the final decission is "should be improved", the flags are disputed automatically...

Comment: [It Keeps Happening](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/sweetbroandhellajeff/): I flagged [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537689/try-hacklang-as-easily-as-possible) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556059/how-to-set-up-skrill-account) and had them marked as "disputed" before being put on hold/deleted. Have there been any changes to the way that flags are marked as "disputed" recently, or is this sudden uptick in disputations simply a very strange coincidence?

Comment: Related (near duplicate): [Flagged as Too Broad and got flag disputed on a deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289258)

Comment: I have the same problem, a lot of my flags today and yesterday are disputed because people hit should be improved if it is off-topic.

Comment: This is getting ridiculous: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29644884/4200092 (disputed)

Comment: No, seriously: [disputed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29676222/4200092), [disputed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29668351/4200092), and [disputed (twice)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29675316/4200092).

Comment: Most ridiculous one I've had so far: [flag on this post was disputed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732366/comment-monter-un-serveur-et-cloud-maison) -- seriously? Would be interested to see what review caused that @BradLarson

Comment: I'm also seeing posts where I have disputed flags getting closed for the same reason.  It has not happened to me too many times, and honestly I got a bit of a chuckle out of it, but now seeing these other complaints I am wondering if there should be some form of automated system to go back and penalize that first batch of reviewers for what can only be explained as failure to understand the meaning of the review buttons, or robo-reviewing (this would be much more important than "fixing" the disputed status on the flag as it would provide education for the users causing the problem)..

Comment: I'm new at rewieving Triage and sometimes a bit unsure, what to do, so often I skip it to let more experienced users take care of it. But it's confusing me and makes me even more unsure, if I'm doing it right, when I see quite a lot of my reviews beeing disputed (22 helpfull, 3 declined, 6 disputed) . Maybe it is because some people thinks a question should be improved and others think it should be closed right away. So I'm asking: Is it a bad thing, when it's disputed or is it just a normal opinion difference between us all?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974752/calculate-values-for-col-e-fg-and-then-resets-and-starts-over

Comment: Couldn't agree more: "something needs to be done". Related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293611/983430

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After reviewing the data on the *final outcomes* of posts flagged in Triage Review, we've added some nuance to how flags are handled in response to review completion.

If the task is completed as...

- **Looks OK**
  ...then close flags are *disputed*, while Spam, Offensive and Very Low Quality flags are *declined*.
- **Should be Improved**
  ...then Spam, Offensive and Very Low Quality flags are *disputed*.
- **Unsalvageable**
  ...then Very Low Quality flags are marked *helpful*.

Except as noted above, all flags (and close votes) are ignored by Triage and will be processed normally (by moderators or in other review queues). This should help to provide more accurate handling and feedback on flags going forward.

This change went into effect roughly one hour ago.

Comment: Do close votes still stick to a post that was marked as looks ok?

Comment: Close **votes** are (and always have been) entirely unaffected by anything that happens in Triage.

Comment: "Unsalvageable" outcome doesn't mention Spam and Offensive flags. I guess that means these flags pass through the normal route then, to moderators or community deletion if enough flags accumulate - correct?

Comment: Correct, @gnat. Most spam/offensive flags are handled expediently that way already.

Comment: understood, thanks. As far as I can tell, safest approach to handle troublesome questions in Triage is "Unsalvageable -> Should be closed..." Worst case, it resolves to painless disputed flag; as for 3K users, they don't have even that risk - it's like they simply vote close

Comment: ...Shog, I can not understand how this interplays with CV queue, could you please help. When do Triage votes and flags push question to close queue ([do they?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293559/839601)) I can ask this as separate question if you prefer