# Is flagging off-topic stuff worthwhile, or just annoying?

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I see a lot of flags I raise from the review queues for off-topic or poor questions being disputed:

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603445/how-to-fix-dota-2-startup

This question is clearly off-topic (it's about a video game, nothing to do with programming). But my flag was disputed -- presumably from people just clicking "looks OK" in a review queue somewhere.

Is it wrong of me to take what I think is the appropriate action in queues / when I see bad questions on the front page? Should I stop wasting the time of everyone involved until I have the power to vote-to-close myself?

---

The text of the question (now deleted) reads:

> My steam cannt open the game (**dota2**).
>
> when i click it always close without alert.
>
> i already followed the instruction for
>
> 1. verfy file,
> 2. turn off DEP (it doesnt work because dota 2 actually a DEP program
> 3. re-install
> 4. update steam
> 5. restore
>
> and all of that step didnt make my dota2 open like usually i got this game from my friends computer, i copied it to my computer and it doesnt work, when i reinstalling and downloading from beginning it doesnt make any change
>
> please help me

Comment: Speaking only as a sub-3000 rep user, I would say no! Please continue flagging questions like these!

Comment: I understand the distinction between disputed / declined -- my question is whether I should give up on review queues until I can actually take action, rather than just flag it and hope people see the problems I see.

Comment: I think this particular question could be a clear example of ***why*** you flagging is still useful. Evidently had you not flagged it it would have sat around and not been dealt with, however now, despite the fact that it was (*IMO incorrectly*) disputed, it can be closed/put on hold if that's the necessary action. I think a lot of terrible questions in less popular tags can be missed by higher-rep users, so our flagging can still provide value.

Comment: *"Is it wrong of me to take what I think is the appropriate action"* - absolutely not! That question was **clearly** off-topic, by the way, and I've no idea why anyone felt otherwise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because unfortunately roboreviewers still exist, I suspect. Thinking about which button to click is just too hard.

Comment: There seems to have been an increase in the number of flag disputations recently. I think I had about 2 "disputed" flags at start of this month; I now have **16**, many of which have since been closed anyway. See [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/4200092) for discussion of this topic.

Comment: It is indeed rather pointless, questions on the long tail of SO cannot get enough votes to ever get closed.  They require moderator intervention, like the one you invoked here.  The review dispute is an unrelated problem, but with the same underlying issue, there are simply not enough votes to help correct a bad review.

Comment: @GoBusto I've noticed the same. I think they must have tweaked / lowered the criteria for the community declining flags -- or the community is just getting worse? :)

Comment: @HansPassant Well, that's rather disheartening. What counts as the "long tail"? I flagged it less than ten minutes after it was asked, while it was still on the front page of "newest questions".

Comment: A tag like [steam] with only 234 questions is firmly on the long tail.  Only tags with more than ~10000 questions have enough SO users looking at them to gather 5 votes to close a question.  Just in case: no, requests to make the number of required votes proportional to the popularity of the tag have been ignored many times in the past.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, ok. Yes, I had no intention of suggesting such a thing. Most of my experience with SE engine is from much smaller sites so I sometimes forget just how much stuff there is on SO. :)

Comment: Thank you @Radiodef for providing the context. :)

Comment: Has it been moved to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman No, and hopefully it won't be.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yeah, [one individual OKed this question, and a number of other reviewers thought it could be made on-topic with a few improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7668289), oblivious to the fact that the question had nothing to do with programming at all.

I've closed the question and handed out some bans.

Comment: I.. err, didn't expect such a drastic response. My aim wasn't to highlight anyone not reviewing well -- I'm just seeking guidance on whether flagging is the right thing for a low-rep user to do to try and help the site with quality. Thank you.

Comment: @TZHX: Some of these users have somewhat of a history of review bans, so for the most part the action is justified.

Comment: Can we please permaban the user that actually clicked "Looks OK"?

Comment: @l4mpi the triages that suggest 'looks ok' or 'improvement' on things that are unsalvageable by users who are less than 2000 rep are symptoms of the misunderstanding of Stack Overflow's quality standards. These are the same people who are *asking* questions of this quality. To them, it does look ok or just needs a tweak here or there.

Comment: @MichaelT which is exactly why we should strive to remove them from this community.

Comment: Why is it even allowed that such low-rep users (as low as 731) can  participate in this queue?

Answer (score 20):

> Is it wrong of me to take what I think is the appropriate action

Of course not! If you subsequently find out that others didn't agree it was appropriate, that's fine too; by design, virtually everything can be undone if required.

> Should I stop wasting the time of everyone involved until I have the power to vote-to-close myself?

I don't think you *are* wasting the time of everyone involved; by contrast, bad questions that stick around without getting properly dealt with **do** waste people's time.

Continue as you are - the flagging functionality exists for a reason, and unless you find yourself getting a lot of rejections you should feel free to use it.