# Has the review process of moderator flags been changed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

In three and a half years, I've had 6 flags disputed, and in the last few weeks I've had 9 flags disputed. I know it doesn't count towards me, but it still annoys me since it either means that I'm doing a bad job flagging, or someone is doing a bad job reviewing.

A few of my recent disputed flags:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510212/expand-a-math-expression (was later closed for the reason I flagged it)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603260/any-library-or-tools-for-displaying-objects-on-a-custom-image-map (asks for a library, I flagged off topic for asking for a library)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603208/activation-email-using-jsp-or-servlet Off topic, same reason as above
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603285/vehicle-motion-detection-in-android Flagged as too broad, but I should probably have flagged it as off topic.

So, as the title, says: Has the review process of moderator flags been changed? Or have I just become a bad flagger and should get my act together?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/4200092 (This bothers me as well - for example, how is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29604935/4200092) question *not* "Too Broad"?)

Comment: @GoBusto Interesting, in particular AJPerez' comment. I hope a moderator or staff member can comment on this.

Comment: These ever increasing piles of garbage that SE collects for people to pick through just turns them into mindless zombie robots.  Vote junk 9 times, the 10th time they'll make a mistake.  There is too much junk.

Comment: A disputed flag isn't the same as a flag that was declined by a moderator - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags.

Comment: It seems like the Triage review queue has been identified as a source of a lot of flags being "disputed" if people review the same post different ways, so maybe it's possible that the rate of "disputed" flags has gone up since that queue was introduced?

Comment: Yes, this appears to be almost entirely due to the Triage reviews where the majority of reviewers chose "Should Be Improved" or "Looks OK". Reviews that disputed your four flags above: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7668193 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7668271 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7668199 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7610908 .

Comment: @BradLarson That explains it. Sloppy/lazy/too nice triage reviewers. Submit your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: That said, you should really have been flagging each of those questions for closure, not as VLQ.  Marking it VLQ in the hopes that enough people in triage might vote to close putting it in the close queue is just adding unnecessary indirection.

Comment: @Servy - These were close flags. The Triage reviews invalidated them, apparently.

Comment: @BradLarson Why are close flags putting the question in triage, and not the close vote queue?