# Flagging Response Inconsistency

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I flagged this question:

[Notes regarding blob tracking based motion tracking [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643389/notes-regarding-blob-tracking-based-motion-tracking)

as off-topic, more precisely that it's about recommending or finding a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.

My flag was marked as disputed.

> off-topic – 5 hours ago  **disputed**

Now I see that the question is put on hold as off-topic.

Why did this happen? When is a flag considered disputed?

Comment: Disputed != Declined.  It just means enough reviewers disagreed with it, but enough reviewers agreed with it that it was not declined.  It doesn't count against you (it is more or less a neutral flag response)

Comment: Ok, but why wasn't it marked as helpful?

Comment: Like I said, enough reviewers disagreed with it.  It is handled like that because it is not a clear enough consensus to say that the flag was helpful or not helpful.

Comment: Well, if some  reviewers disagreed with it, while it actually turned out off-topic, shouldn't they get a warning or something? And also, turn my flag from disputed to helpful? The process of reviewing flags should be somehow connected with the process of putting questions on hold. It is actually discouraging for users that flag posts.

Comment: This question may also be relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/4200092

Comment: @enb081 why should they get a warning.  Who is to say a small majority of a handful of people is right?  Who is to say they are wrong.  The simple fact is there is no consensus so declaring your flag helpful in the absence of a consensus is not appropriate.  The post was closed, so if you felt it should be closed, then you did your job.  If you are worrying about 1 flag that wasn't marked as helpful, then you are worrying about the wrong thing.

Comment: Well, the post certainly wasn't closed because of what I did, and this happened because reviewers didn't do their job. The thing is what's the point of even bothering of raising *helpful* flags  if they are not even taken into consideration.