# Disputed off-topic flag on question about hard drive partitions

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

[I raised a flag on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663334/linux-mount-wrong-partition-in-fusion) claiming it was off topic due to the fact that it was not related to programming and more suitable for SuperUser; the flag was disputed.

Is this ruling correct? If so, why?

Comment: Triage reviews, once again: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7703655 . Lots of "Looks OK" in there.

Comment: [I love this userscript...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LENhK.png)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/4200092

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a fine flag - the question does not appear to be programming-related. Reviewers aren't perfect - sometimes they screw up.

Comment: Ok, no worries, I was just checking to see if I missed something obvious being new to the who reviewing game and all. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are giving the reviewers too much credit here.

Comment: Some reviewers aren't perfect. Others are dunber than the quality score bot.