# "Underwhelming" question, disputed flag, the end?

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

This is the first time I've encountered a disputed flag and I don't get it. I've read [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag). Here's the scenario:

Bad question from low-rep user (I don't mean low-rep like me, I mean like nonexistent). It's bad because:

- The whole problem was the user didn't pass required arguments to a function (and they are clearly documented as required for the library in question).
- The code formatting is messed up.
- The user later posted a comment (not even an answser) saying they fixed it by adding the required arguments.

So now there's this "question" with like 35 lines of code sitting there where the only relevant thing is that the required args weren't passed in one function call. Until I came along there was no activity except from the OP: no votes, no answers, no comments. I flagged it as very low quality (VLQ) and left a comment. Later I see that the flag is "disputed". So I look at [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) and the reasons it lists for why that could happen don't apply here: no edit, no upvote, no accept (not even any answers).

So according to [What happens to a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135813/what-happens-to-a-disputed-flag) it sounds like a 10k user just marked it as invalid? And that's it? I could go and edit this question to fix the code formatting and then post an answer that rehashes what the OP posted in their comment: the required arguments are required. But what's the point? This question is just clutter and should just go away.

Comment: This doesn't answer the disputed flag, but you could use the off-topic flag reason "Can no longer be reproduced/due to a __typographical error__".

Comment: Downvote, cast a CV as "typo" (it's not a typo, but crap like this is just as unhelpful to anybody else as a typo), move on. If it gets closed that should be sufficient to get the question cleaned up by the roomba. Do _not_ answer if you're interested in getting the question deleted, if somebody upvotes the answer the question won't get auto-deleted.

Comment: It's not necessarily 10k users. It could be pretty much anyone with access to the triage review queues (1000 rep minimum?).

Comment: Obligatory: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/4200092

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I want to shout out user [@rene](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) here. Elsewhere I asked about how I can find the review queue page for a question and @rene spent a bunch of time talking me through it and constructed this [awesome query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/301979) to illustrate for me how to find the page once the necessary data is in SEDE. I still don't understand why stackoverflow doesn't just link to the review page from the question or allow you to search for it by question ID.

Comment: After much jumping through hoops, finally tracked down the review page for the post in question. @TZHX -- 3 sub-700 users marked it as "Looks OK", while 2 other users (lower rep than me, higher than the other 3) marked it as "Should Be Improved". Now somebody else edited it to fix the code formatting (and I think upvoted it), and piggybacked their own question on in the form of a comment.

Comment: @TZHX I have 664 rep as of now and I have access to Triage queues.