# My flags are being marked as disputed but then question is being put on hold for the same reason

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I've recently flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995494/sending-user-input-java) as too broad. The question was put on hold for being too broad however my flag was disputed.

This happened again when I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064996/premiers-pas-raytracer-en-c-lambart-phong-and-blinn) as unclear what you're asking. It was also put on hold for unclear what you're asking, but my flag was disputed as well.

Can this be corrected, or am I doing something wrong when flagging?

Note: I'm not asking what is the difference between disputed/declined or helpful.

Comment: It's just some careless reviewing or by accident. Don't frown upon it too much. Move on. There's no way to change a disputed flag. But the questions have been put on hold. That 's what's important.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about it, just wanted to get some insight on why/how this would happen.

Comment: @l-l, when you flag a post, it comes to one of the review queue's. Someone there must have just hit the "Looks Okay" without even bothering to read. There's not much you can do about that. So move on, and don't let this discourage you in the future.

Comment: And also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday

Comment: @l-l , the diagram in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) will help you understand.

Comment: @ArunA.S thanks, I will take a look at it.

Comment: In this particular case, it was disputed by triage review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7911805