# VLQ flag rejected by "moderator" - have I missed something? What happened?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I'm not ranting, just puzzled/curious as to why it was rejected.

Yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992017/2632129) as VLQ.

In case it gets deleted, here's the answer I flagged *in full*:

> have U tried with --disable-selinux configure option ?

Today I noticed my flag was rejected because:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

---

The answer is *not* fit for NAA due to the *specific* reasons to use NAA, but it is VLQ because:

1. It's a "question" asking the OP for clarification. It is one small
   sentence with a question mark. An *answer* would have been "You
   *need to* use `disable-selinux-etc`"
2. The grammar is bad and there is no code formatting. While it could
   be edited easily it does add to being Low Quality (I would *not*
   have flagged VLQ if it actually answered the question, I'd have just
   edited)
3. Answerer has 1 rep so cannot comment, I believed they used answer to
   ask for clarification
4. From my knowledge of reviewing I knew that one of the options in the
   VLQ queue would fit this scenario perfectly:

   > This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
   >   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their
   >   post.

---

1:
Is there a specific reason why this was rejected? Have I missed something, is it not VLQ?

2:
Does the message really mean an actual moderator reviewed it and rejected? I ask this as there is [some confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251061/230506) in the system as to what "moderator" means as the grand total in our flag history is labelled "moderator attention flags".

Comment: Just because something has a question mark doesn't make it "not an answer." Just ask Socrates.

Comment: Ah the VLQ misunderstanding - its the one flag to confuse them all.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=VLQ . Just to note: the flag is not just there to taunt you. I managed to flag an 'answer' with it today that matched the criteria that TZHX mentions and it actually did pass ;)

Comment: Don't you think that people may phrase statements as questions when they aren't 100% sure that they are correct? People may phrase statements as questions when they aren't 100% sure that they are correct.  *See what I did thar?*

Comment: @Will Firstly that's bad grammar. Either ask a question or make a statement. I hate when people write a statement which is not a question but put a question mark on the end to signify "I'm not sure if this is right so am partly asking as well as telling". Either tell or ask. Secondly, my entire question here is not hinged around the bit I mentioned a question mark. there are *other points* made.

Answer (score 6):

> 1:
>   Is there a specific reason why this was rejected? Have I missed something, is it not VLQ?

Yes. "Very Low Quality" is meant for posts like: "saodinfsgo sko vsinfgso bsd bsoi fs." Complete nonsense with no value.

The post you link to *tries* to provide a response to the question -- but does so in a way more suited to a comment and / or text message. The more appropriate flag in this case would be, I think, "Not an answer". If this gets to a moderator, it still may be declined, but it's more likely to be left to the community and the Low Quality review queue to deal with as you say.

> 2:
>   Does the message really mean an actual moderator reviewed it and rejected? I ask this as there is some confusion in the system as to what "moderator" means as the grand total in our flag history is labelled "moderator attention flags".

Yes -- the system explicitly saying a moderator reviewed your flag means an actual moderator reviewed your flag.

If it were a system process, the flag would simply say "declined".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I disagree with you and think you have "NAA" and "VLQ" usage reasons mixed up. "*Very Low Quality" is meant for posts like: 'saodinfsgo sko vsinfgso bsd bsoi fs.' Complete nonsense with no value.*" Not if you look at the "Recommend delete" reasons - there are all sorts of reasons to delete as Low Quality. Should be a comment; is another question; should be an edit to the question; Link only; NAA is for "kjhdfjkhd fjsdfjks dfjsdf". Feel free to debate if you disagree, I'm happy to be put right if that's the case.

Comment: @James The flag is "**Very** Low Quality", the review queue is "Low Quality". There's a scale difference. VLQ flag says (emphasis mine): `This answer has **severe** formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.`

Comment: @James No, you have that completely backwards.  And it's not a matter of opinion to disagree on.  If a post isn't an answer, it should be flagged as NAA, not VLQ.  If a post is of such low quality that it's completely worthless, and also completely unsalvageable, then it should be flagged as VLQ.  Neither of those are true of this answer; it's not of no value, as it's proposing a solution, and while it has problems, they're problems that can be fixed with editing, making it a salvageable post.

Comment: Flags can be marked declined by a system process. The only way to tell if a flag was declined by a moderator is by the presence of a message.

Comment: @BoltClock Does the absence of a message mean that it *wasn't* handled by a moderator, then?

Comment: @TZHX: Yes; it'll be the outcome of a review task instead (close/reopen reviews I think).

Comment: @TZHX - To follow on what BoltClock said, "very low quality" flags are now declined in review with predominantly "Looks OK" reviews: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday/300787#300787

Comment: So do NAA flags get pushed into the VLQ?

Comment: @BradLarson so, as triage only deals with questions, is that also relevant for flags on answers (does Low Quality Posts also *decline* rather than *dispute*)?

Comment: @TZHX - Yes, I believe similar rules apply for Low Quality Posts reviews.