# VLQ flag declined by moderator through edit?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

Today I was checking my flagging history and found out one of my VLQ flags was declined by a moderator. Apparently the answer was not VLQ, and it was my lack of subject knowledge combined with a poorly formatted answer. In hindsight I ofcourse should have skipped.

Anyway the flag was cast, and it was rejected. Assumably correct.

However this is the first time I noticed that a moderator declined my VLQ flag. Thinking of all the different flags that are out there VLQ doesn't immediatly come to mind when thinking of important flags that moderators should care about. I went to the answer in question and saw that a moderator edited the question, to give it propper formatting and spelling. It now does indeed look like a reasonable answer.

So did this edit from a moderator automatically decline my VLQ flag, or did a moderator happen to stroll past tye VLQ queue?

I read: [VLQ flag rejected by "moderator" - have I missed something? What happened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304199/vlq-flag-rejected-by-moderator-have-i-missed-something-what-happened) but didn't find a real answer there.

Comment: I don't see how helpfully declining an inappropriate flag while contributing to shaping up the post on which it was cast would be a case of "hav[ing] too much time on their hands".

Comment: IIRC Edits do automatically clear VLQ flags on posts... or maybe it's just NAA flags?

Comment: @duplode, that was not my point. Did it happen just because a mod edited that post, for what ever reason the specific mod chose to edit that answer. Or is there some manual moderator input required?

Comment: @Luuklag Then I suggest editing your question to say that more clearly, in a way that doesn't frame what happened as somehow abnormal.

Comment: @duplode, you are right, reading it again it does indeed give that signal. That was not my intention. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not too much time. Too little time.

I can jump into some crazy vote fraud case, try to clear up some dispute over code indentation, or do any number of diamond-only things. Those things are, indisputably, more useful than handling VLQ flags with a hammer. Problem is, they also take way more time and commitment. I can't just stop halfway through sussing out a bunch of socks.

When I've got four minutes to handle stuff in the morning, clearing a few dozen easy flags is helpful, doesn't require a huge time commitment, and is kinda therapeutic. Like flag candy.

---

I declined the flag based on [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50565818/1), which was useful and likely even correct. My iOS is rusty, but the proposed solution sounds right. Then I edited it to format some things and remove punctuation. The edit came after the decline; by default, an edit marks VLQ flags *helpful*.

Don't rely on the review queues being lenient (and often downright delete-happy). You should assume that a moderator is going to look at every flag you cast, because there's a decent chance we will.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clear things up. Good to know you are indeed human and do require therapy once in a while ;) So no intriquete site mechanisms involved at all, just a "simple" human being.

Comment: @Luuklag Yep. The only real mechanism involved here is that, by default, we don't see NAA/VLQ flags until they're at least an hour old. Gives the review queues *some* time to handle things before they reach us.