# Can we be more consistent about handling NAA/VLQ flags?

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, declined-flags, not-an-answer

**Edit:** I disagree that my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/2378429); I am asking about the discrepancy between audits that require action and can be passed by flagging for *NAA* (or even *VLQ*) and "real" reviews of posts that have the same issues but where an *NAA*/*VLQ* flag would surely be declined. There a lot of them; I have passed most of the ones that I encountered but I'm not happy with the discrepancy since it keeps quality standards inconsistent. Hence my question.

I have recently started [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review) **First Posts** and **Late Answers** on Stack Overflow. In the process, one inevitably encounters many bad answers; I have been flagging these where I deemed appropriate. For guidance I used [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2378429) excellent answer.

After having a number of **NAA** and one **VLQ** flag declined, I have started flagging with less zeal since apparently the standard for "answer" (as in not *NAA*) is pretty low. As a consequence of this, I have failed some audits, most recently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/20168803) one, and am now review-banned, for the second time. Personally, I think we should hold answers to a high standard, so I don't think the post is a particularly valuable answer. But it seems to me, given the meta answer linked above and my recent declined flags, that it should not be flagged as *NAA* – so it should not have been an audit.

Now, having some bad audits seems inevitable, but this isn't the first one I have encountered where I actually would like to flag as *NAA*, but the rules tell me otherwise.

So I would like to ask: Can we handle *NAA* (and possibly *VLQ*, although maybe they're more [clear-cut](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304199/vlq-flag-rejected-by-moderator-have-i-missed-something-what-happened)) more consistently, so that we can either flag with confidence, or have fewer questionable audits? I would prefer to uphold a higher standard for answers, but I'm not going to do that if my flags just keep getting declined (since that's a pretty clear indication that I'm doing it wrong).

Alternatively, if you think the way *NAA* flags are handled is fine, I would really appreciate some guidance (beyond the posts I have linked) as to when to flag as *NAA*. Because right now, I'm not sure how to proceed once I'm no longer review banned – I'd rather not get another ban, but flagging as *NAA* when I'm probably going to get declined is not great either, as it wastes the time of those handling the flags.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308374/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-part-2-can-we-stop-the-confusion-about-naa-fla

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the link; I had read part 1 but was unaware of part 2. I have read it now, and it seems it mostly deals with the "apples vs oranges" issue; this is not what my question is about. I am asking regarding answers that address the question, but are of very little value (eg not link-only, but close, or less than five words).

Comment: There is another discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 This is the one I have linked in my question. It‘s good, but applying it rigorously does not have the desired result.

Comment: @O.O.Balance those kind of little value answers are why we have downvotes. Feel free to dish those out as and when.

Comment: @RobertLongson So there are just a lot of bad audits? I‘m not just talking about the handful that I have failed, the ones I have passed are many more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: @gnat That probably cannot be said often enough. I already skip a lot of reviews though; and from the guidance available on NAA flagging I would actually say that I‘m not unsure about reviewing – just conflicted.

Comment: you don't skip enough as evidenced by your audit failure. You said it yourself, "I don't think the post is a particularly valuable answer" - this is the absolutely strong reason to skip, and you failed the audit because you didn't do this

Comment: @gnat Sorry, but I disagree. If I really have to skip even more reviews, I'll probably stop reviewing FP/LA. The audit is bad when it tells you flagging for *VLQ* is valid when in reality the flag would certainly be declined. In the real world, "Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer!" (see the linked answer in my post) gets applied pretty consistently to *NAA* flags and *VLQ* is even worse ("gibberish", see the guidance on using that flag on meta in several places).

Comment: @O.O.Balance "So there are just a lot of bad audits?" - difficult to say. There are definitely audits based on really bad moderation decisions - those are often fixed when reported on meta. However there is also the grey area of audits which are exceptionally misleading; a good example is a bit of content which looks fine but was deleted as spam because the author was a known spammer. Are those bad audits? Or actually really good, given that the function of an audit is to make sure you're paying attention?

Comment: @Gimby When reviewing, it is not required to be familiar with the posting history of the author. If there's nothing in a post to suggest it's spam, it should not be an audit. It does however help to visit the author's profile if the answer contains a link – often you can find the same website there or the name matches. In those cases, it's spam (and a legitimate audit) due to lack of disclosure of affiliation.

Comment: well if you want to feel comfortable easily approving suspicious posts then it's indeed better to stop reviewing FP/LA. There are tens thousands users eligible to do these reviews and I think enough of them will feel okay sticking with more thorough and critical approach. See also: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/839601) (given recent comments this may be even better duplicate than I initially suggested)

Comment: @gnat I don't think you're hearing me: I don't want to review to a lower standard at all. My approach to reviewing is thorough and critical, but I do look at the flags that are declined. I just don't want to flag for *NAA* when the flag is just going to be declined (causing more work for those handling flags). Refer to CodeCaster's answer. As for the audits, they routinely suggest flagging in cases where it's simply not warranted (that does not mean the post is not "suspicious", which btw I do recognise).

Comment: @O.O.Balance You don't have to take notice of the author at all, the only thing you have to do is go to the question page and notice the content is not there. That is the easiest way to catch any audit, good or bad. But... it takes time.

Comment: @Gimby While certainly true, this is not the way you're supposed to handle audits ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when to flag as NAA

Almost never.

Quite some users want to get rid of low-quality answers, but VLQ nor NAA are the correct flags there. The only recommended course of action is to downvote and move on.

Unless an answer literally states *"Thanks, this helped me!"*, or *"I'm having this problem too, how did you solve it?"* or *"wharrgarbl"*, you can't flag it as NAA because then the mods will have to actually read and evaluate the correctness of the answer, which they don't want to.

The VLQ flag is equally useless, and I can't find any uniform advice about its application. You can't use it for poorly formatted posts, you can't use it for incorrect posts, you [can't really use it anytime](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314679/how-do-vlq-flags-work-whats-their-relationship-to-the-lqp-queue-whats-their):

> If you think that the post could be improved by you, the community, or the author, no matter how remote that possibility, don't flag it.

So while it seems counter-productive, either skip every review where you doubt the correct course of action, or stop reviewing altogether. It is busywork.

If you want to be able to get rid of very poor-quality answers that appear to attempt to answer the question at hand but spectacularly fail to do so if you actually read the answer, then get some more reputation until you can cast delete-votes.

Comment: OT: Wharrgarbl is the best sounding bit of gibberish I've heard in a long time. Definitely going to be the name of a future game character.

Comment: @Gimby It's an old meme. (sprinkler dog)

Comment: Honestly, I'd love to delete many of the answers with these flags, but my hands are tied by the site's policies on how we handle these types of answers. I reckon we should be more rigorous in deleting posts.