# Add a link to the timeline of a post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timeline

There have been many questions on this topic already. For instance:

- [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post)
- [Why is there no link to timeline of the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262678/why-is-there-no-link-to-timeline-of-the-post)

Answers posted in 2014 or 2015 said that this feature was experimental, but now it's 2017! After years of development and optimization [since Jan 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view), current timelines seem nice and neat to me, so I think this feature would be received very well<s>, at least better than SO Documentation</s>.

For those who don't know this feature, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/340703/timeline) is the timeline for this post. As Jeff Atwood said in [his original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) (emphasis mine): "timelines can only be accessed through URL hackery *at the moment*":

```
http://{site}.stackexchange.com/posts/{id}/timeline
```

Comment: The available userscripts work just fine.

Comment: @rene: True, but then why would any site ever update, if there's a userscript that does the same thing?

Comment: @rene Yes, but installing userscripts inevitably requires effort (I'm a Safari user). More importantly, many users don't know SE has such a great feature!

Comment: The feature comes at the price of performance, I guess. Making it available to everyone might interfere with the speed of other functions. Beyond that, it isn't a feature that is widely useful for all of us. Only those who care benefit from it. And I'm sorry for you that you're forced to use Safari.

Comment: It could be auto-enabled at a certain rep level. The link really only is useful when you have some moderation ability, any way.

Comment: I typically access it by middle-clicking the "edit" button and manually changing `/edit` to `/timeline` in the URL, which is just as easy as installing some user script thingy.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: "middle-click"? Are you on a RISC-OS machine?

Comment: @RadLexus I'm not sure what you mean with that, but "middle click" is typically understood as clicking with the scroll wheel button, which almost all mice have and is typically in the *middle* of the left and right buttons. This will open the link in a new tab. You can also use Control+left click if you prefer.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: RISC-OS machines such as the Acorn Archimedes came with a 3-button mouse, and "middle-click" or "centre-click" was the third common option, along with left (direct selection) and right (popup menu). Alas for the trip down Memory Lane: I have an Apple Magic Mouse, so I don't even have buttons. Still a good tip, though - thanks.

Comment: @rene What I ask for is nothing more than a simple link. Please note that the timeline function is already implemented. It's just "hidden" from the public. Also, how often do you "favorite" a question? That large star is still there, jsut below the two vote buttons, although not many people would make use of it.

Comment: @RadLexus I'm a poor trackpad user :(

Comment: The link is not the problem, (too much) people using it might. Rendering the timeline  takes time because posthistory is a large table. It is somewhat similar to seeing the votes break down on posts. That *hidden* feature comes at 1000 rep but is available via userscripts when < 1K.

Comment: @rene The votes break down is available via userscripts to <1k ers? I thought it's a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) to see that!

Comment: @SunQingyao you can use the Stack API `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=4&filter=!-*f(6qtpml44&site=stackoverflow&run=true`

Comment: @rene: TIL you can bypass some privileges if you are enthusiast enough, seems perfectly fitting of SO :D

Comment: Here is a bookmarklet which opens a new tab/window with the post's timeline: `javascript:void(window.open(location.href.replace('questions','posts').replace(/[0-9]{4,}\/.*#([0-9]{4,})/,'$1/').replace(/([0-9]{4,})\/.*/,'$1/timeline')))` Bookmarklet that changes the current tab to the post's timeline: `javascript:void(location.href=location.href.replace('questions','posts').replace(/[0-9]{4,}\/.*#([0-9]{4,})/,'$1/').replace(/([0-9]{4,})\/.*/,'$1/timeline'))` Note that these are based on the URL currently being viewed, not your scroll position on the page.

Comment: @SunQingyao I use Safari, too. I’ve found http://tampermonkey.net/ to be a very good userscript manager (I have >20 installed with no obvious delay on SE).

Comment: I didn't even know this feature until I use [SOX](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/31042)

Comment: The userscript I use that provides this link on all posts is [SE Modifications](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a). It also provides a couple of additional nice features (some of the features it used to provide have been integrated as native functionality). There are also various other userscripts on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) which provide this link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The link for the timeline has now been added for questions and answers, for all users. More details [are available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/51).

Answer (score 12):

It's again nearly 2 years gone since this question. I support bringing it now.

So:

- it's working
- it looks decent
- it adds value in information

Theoreticly we can make it offical with just one Link. What is preventing it from beeing alive?

[image: Timeline Suggestion]

<sub>To forestall the compulsory comment, I will take 6-8 weeks seriously</sub>