# Where can I find the result of my close vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

On Dec 28th I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854302/opencart-failed-to-load-url-response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redirect) which now shows no close votes and the text:

> You have already voted to close this question, but you may vote again on Jan 30 at 3:01

I am aware of the "closure" sub-tab under the "votes" tab in my user profile, but it only shows timestamp the word "closure" and the question title, and I can't seem to find anywhere else on Stack Overflow that shows the result of my votes. Did it expire? Was the question voted to be left open? I'm just a bit confused about what happened to my vote here and how I can find out about the result of close votes in general.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions . In short: close votes age away after 4 days when the question has at least 100 views (not the case here), or otherwise after 14 days (likely: bingo).

Comment: I see.. would be great if there was something less ambiguous to refer to.  Looks like the timeline link mentioned below is what I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed, something similar to the overview of what happened to your flags. There you can see the exact flagging history and their status, which includes a flag simply having aged away.

Comment: @Gimby I want that! ...and I wonder if such a [meta-tag:feature-request] would get gunned down... and then a little pie chart (!) that shows your %efficiency at closing questions (closed/remained-open/expired/hammered).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Do a search in meta.stackexchange.com (because this is not specific to StackOverflow it's better to look on the overmeta site), you'll probably find a few that are on your "do want" list. Example: [give me statistics about my own close vote accuracy!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248267/268911)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47854302/timeline) the question has not been closed, so your vote has simply expired.

When you want to view the timeline of a question, replace `questions` with `posts` and the question title with `timeline`. Example:

- Question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854302/opencart-failed-to-load-url-response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redirect`
- Timeline: `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47854302/timeline`

Comment: Thanks - is there a convenient way to reach that link without manually editing the url?

Comment: @billynoah there is a userscript that you can install https://stackapps.com/questions/4148/view-post-timeline. This can be used with greasemonkey or tampermonkey extension. It will provide a link to the timeline below each post

Comment: We really should file a feature request to add a timeline link directly to posts. It's so useful if you engage at all in moderating activities and yet so annoying to get to.

Comment: @jpmc26 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340703/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post :)

Comment: Or simply click on the timeline button below the voting and save buttons.

Answer (score 2):

### How can I find my close votes? / Where can I find the results of my close votes?

You have to look at each question individually that you voted to close, and see if your vote is still there with the closure still pending or not.

To see your close votes: click your **reputation score** in the top-right --> **Votes** --> **Closure**. You'll see a list of close votes you cast. Click the question links to manually inspect if the question is closed or not.

Here's a redacted screenshot of mine, with the pertinent places to click and view highlighted:

[image]

The URL to this page will look something like this, and appears to be a private page visible only to yourself:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4561887/gabriel-staples?tab=votes