# Vote Summary in Timeline

Tags: discussion, privileges, timeline

In the new feature the timeline, you can see the number of votes up and down. Since anyone can see this no matter what the reputation is, then this makes the following privilege:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

totally useless...

**Picture for evidence:**

[image]

Comment: Wasn't there also a userscript that let <1K people get that vote breakdown? So it's not like it's new...

Comment: Are you sure that the information is available for low rep users? At least on MSE I don't see a breakdown of the votes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't new [here's a post asking for a link to it from 2017, noting that it was experimental in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340703/215552). Ah! What's new is there is a link to it now.

Comment: Nevermind I'm not sure if it appears for low rep. The thing is I opened stackoverflow.com in incognito and saw the button and immediately thought it would appear before even clicking on the button. But now I clicked and the votes count doesn't appear, only events appear.

Answer (score 15):

> Since anyone can see this no matter what the reputation is

Low-rep users that haven't yet reached that privilege **can't see the breakdown**; this is what my 1-point test account sees:

> [image: screenshot of the same timeline page from the perspective of a low-reputation user (1 point), with only "score: -2" shown]

Don't assume that that page is exactly the same for all reputation levels.