# How can I check if a question was edited since it was closed?

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions

I voted to close a question, and it was later closed. Today I navigated to the same question, and I see that it was edited. The question, including the close-banner, now looks like this:

```
...

Closed 6 days ago by anatolyg, xxx, yyy.

(Viewable by ...)

...

edited May 4 at 21:19
```

I see that the question was edited, so maybe I should vote to reopen it? But if it was edited before it was closed, I shouldn't ever bother reading it.

The date `May 4` was roughly 6 days ago, so the editing date doesn't help.

Comment: Check the post timeline, it has [the exact close time and edit times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABz9W.png), in order. Side note, it shouldn't matter if it was edited after the closure, what should matter is if it was edited after *you* voted to close it. If you're waiting until after full closure you're letting other peoples close votes affect your judgement

Comment: Why does it matter whether it was edited before or after it was closed? If you think it's a good question in its current state, then it deserves a reopen vote either way.

Comment: Sometimes I want to make the decision quickly. If I think about each question, I might miss out on other fun stuff in life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply turn to the timeline, either via typing the URL yourself (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340703/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) for example), or by clicking on that "stop watch like" icon below the vote count/arrows:

[image: icons]

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without going to the timeline, is to simply *hover* over the section showing the date, and it'll show you exactly when the question was closed in a `title` attribute. For example, for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript):

> [image]

I find the absolute dates much more informative at a glance than the fuzzy `N ${timeUnit}s ago` that are shown in post notices and use a [userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Post-Notices-Absolute-Dates) to automatically replace the fuzzy dates with the absolute dates, to make comparison easier:

> [image]

---

> But if it was edited before it was closed, I shouldn't ever bother reading it.

That's not the right approach. Best to judge a post *as it is* currently, no matter when or how it may have been edited, and no matter how many close (or reopen) votes it has, and no matter whether it's currently closed or not. Close votes aren't always correct even without considering edits by the OP.

Comment: Nice userscript! :)